# How to click on a button with just a text?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a button that has no class, id just a text

```
 <button> Click me </button>
```

I tried the following:

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//button[contains(text(), 'Click me'")]
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//button(text() = 'Clck me'")
```

None of these work. Could someone put me in the right path?

Comment: You should add `id` then

Comment: Are you missing some quotes?

Comment: do you use capybara gem?

Comment: you should do the button with an id then

Comment: Agree. Best practice is to use ids. Because the button text may change, structure may change and even button may become an anchor tag.

Comment: Looks like you got some spaces around it in html and which are missing in finding element? Or provide some more html code snippet for better context.

Comment: Its not a site I designed. Does not have access to the code

Comment: Its not a site I designed. Does not have access to the code. Cannot add a class or anything. I am just illustrating that the button has no id, class, etc just a button with a text

Comment: Any errors raised?

Comment: Its not able to find the element @Andersson

Comment: You may find a parent, or grandparent, wrapping element that does have a unique id that you can use in your path.  e.g. //div[@id='foo']/button

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like syntactically incorrect, You should try as :-

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//button[normalize-space(text())='Click me']")
```

or

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//button[contains(text(), 'Click me')]")
```

**Note** :- Your button text seems as **contains extra white spaces**. So for avoiding these white spaces you should use `normalize-space()` in your `xPath`

Hope it will help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your xpath. The correct one is:

```
# use button[] instead of button()
# you have weird order of ", ' and )
# space in the text 'Click me' also be considered ' Click me '
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//button[text() = ' Click me ']")
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not your typo in question, Try after changing:

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//button[contains(text(), 'Click me'")]
```

to

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//button[contains(text(), 'Click me')]")
```

Otherwise, find all the element on the page with tag name as "button" then traverse through the list of those elements to get the desired one.

**Eg Code:**

Get all buttons:

```
buttons =  driver.find_elements(:class=> 'button');
```

Get the button with text 'Click Me'

```
clickMeButton = buttons.select{|el| el.text == 'Click Me'}.first
```

click on the button:

```
clickMeButton.click
```